# Failed to connect to localhost orientdb using jdbc

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 2.1.9 and has created plocal graph database called 'TimespentEvents'.

When trying to connect from Java using JDBC driver in the same machine with URL 'jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/TimespentEvents' and user/password admin/admin I encounter the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on opening database: the engine 'remote' was not found. URL was: remote:localhost/TimespentEvents. Registered engines are: [plocal, memory]
```

When changing the URL into 'jdbc:orient:plocal:TimespentEvents' the error turns into:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open the storage 'TimespentEvents' because it does not exist in path: localhost/TimespentEvents
```

Below is the jdbc driver jars I include in the classpath:

- orientdb-jdbc-2.1.9.jar
- orientdb-core-2.1.9.jar

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Setya

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I have to include 2 additional jars:

- orientdb-enterprise-2.1.9.jar
- orientdb-client-2.1.9.jar

Thanks & Regards,

Setya

Comment: including orientdb-client-*.jar was sufficient for me.